# docker swarm on oracle cloud instance results in unreachable overlay network

Tags: linux, docker, networking, cloud, docker-swarm

My docker swarm setup consists of 3 nodes

- home-server `anton`
- digital-ocean `zeus`
- oracle cloud always-free ARM instance `galio`

I'm using [`traefik/whoami`](https://github.com/traefik/whoami) to test the connectivity, deployed it on all of those 3 nodes, with `traefik` load balancer set up on `zeus`.

When making requests, it works only for 2 first requests, but third one fails with 502 or 504 HTTP Status code. And traefik reports `caused by: dial tcp 10.0.1.27:80: connect: no route to host"`, where the specified address is IP of `galio`

#### Oracle Cloud subnet security list

[image: security list]

#### IPTables configuration

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Sep  4 23:12:52 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [9:1455]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [12503:4589221]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
:InstanceServices - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2376 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 7946 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 7946 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 4789 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker_gwbridge -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker_gwbridge -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker_gwbridge ! -o docker_gwbridge -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j InstanceServices
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.4/32 ! -i docker_gwbridge -o docker_gwbridge -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker_gwbridge ! -o docker_gwbridge -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.2/32 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 3260 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.2.0/24 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 3260 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.4.0/24 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 3260 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.5.0/24 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 3260 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.3/32 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -m tcp --dport 80 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.0.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 69 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
-A InstanceServices -d 169.254.169.254/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -m comment --comment "See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule" -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Sep  4 23:12:52 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Sep  4 23:12:52 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.0/16 ! -o docker_gwbridge -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.4/32 -d 172.18.0.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i docker_gwbridge -j RETURN
-A DOCKER ! -i docker_gwbridge -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.4:80
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Sep  4 23:12:52 2022
```

#### Docker networks

`gbaranski@zeus > docker network inspect trafik-public`

```json
[
    {
        "Name": "traefik-public",
        "Id": "xkpqua30neu7abr9ldw86klfr",
        "Created": "2022-09-02T04:38:24.799603491Z",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.1.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.1.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "1d321acce71c3cde5f3c31f48f5844924b6a15c8a5ff4364f7c45a2369140363": {
                "Name": "portainer_portainer.1.6sni6kg0mh7f2g1ngefj0pwke",
                "EndpointID": "4a21396de7ecd673cc69f3dacf92e20b3544e8a247ec1175843ebe3221020a73",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:01:05",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.1.5/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "36116f03bb4cae6328e66a1bb58d57fd73c24f2b7b4ee3e5223040a50896fba4": {
                "Name": "traefik_traefik.1.qfnkxhjptjhjc3u77zp9erfy7",
                "EndpointID": "58517905ec50479b23a3d1435f9ae97941524ecd73f2bbc3844aafb906478863",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:01:1d",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.1.29/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "df674f10547d23eca3bb6f495965f08e8f1cabbe663eff3b67f7cdb90e29d99b": {
                "Name": "whoami_whoami.3.l4bl4483mk2zlhxrtqewmldl8",
                "EndpointID": "77239ba8e1b9050c18dd00773df6bda90891ca1184f880b308cb649e87036d66",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:01:0b",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.1.11/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "lb-traefik-public": {
                "Name": "traefik-public-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "17152c3ebc528ce5c4b0aacd240e1b92fc5dcc416ce48696795efc195e418592",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:01:03",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.1.3/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4097"
        },
        "Labels": {},
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "169a1a886742",
                "IP": "207.154.xxx.xxx"
            },
            {
                "Name": "6fb47e278ac1",
                "IP": "109.241.xxx.xxx"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

`gbaranski@galio > docker network inspect trafik-public`

```json
[
    {
        "Name": "traefik-public",
        "Id": "xkpqua30neu7abr9ldw86klfr",
        "Created": "2022-09-04T23:19:05.345265356Z",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.1.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.1.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "1c3125187edfe1ee371190cccdb25dd21dbfc9f1e8372038f4ebd23beda2c217": {
                "Name": "whoami_whoami.2.vc5w3es8d6a72byolgcc0mdxy",
                "EndpointID": "77046f345f6747e08ad86ddfcf8028093ca9b3d3fda38464e274518e72681af7",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:01:1b",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.1.27/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "lb-traefik-public": {
                "Name": "traefik-public-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "834eda51dac95ccdfcd0189591e54eb72905405c0b649499b701f532888c52f9",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:01:1c",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.1.28/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4097"
        },
        "Labels": {},
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "6fb47e278ac1",
                "IP": "109.241.xxx.xxx"
            },
            {
                "Name": "169a1a886742",
                "IP": "207.154.xxx.xxx"
            },
            {
                "Name": "fbc321e19b68",
                "IP": "10.0.0.28"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

As you can see, `Peers` in `docker network inspect` from `galio` also includes some peer with IP of 10.0.0.28, which is its address in subnet.

`gbaranski@galio > ip a`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:00:17:06:b5:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.28/24 metric 100 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::17ff:fe06:b5bd/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker_gwbridge: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:6a:ea:b0:9d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global docker_gwbridge
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:6aff:feea:b09d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:21:37:86:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: veth4d81564@if9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker_gwbridge state UP group default
    link/ether 4e:8d:3a:5c:50:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::4c8d:3aff:fe5c:5076/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
20: vethfa32c51@if19: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker_gwbridge state UP group default
    link/ether ae:a2:15:c7:30:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 4
    inet6 fe80::aca2:15ff:fec7:3040/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
27: vethd70f359@if26: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker_gwbridge state UP group default
    link/ether e6:a9:2f:1c:9a:fd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 7
    inet6 fe80::e4a9:2fff:fe1c:9afd/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solved

I had to join the swarm with `--advertise-addr` flag. So for example

```
docker swarm join --token <token> 207.154.xxx.xxx:2377 --advertise-addr 130.61.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: Thank you! I was getting crazy about this trying to set up portainer-ce and agents. Even looking at `docker node inspect <node-id>` didn't show any clue about this issue, it was showing the same local IP that I provided now as `advertise-addr` (and now is working properly). Where you found this information?